Using a bistable solenoid valve with arduino from battery
Context
I have been trying for some time to control a 4.5 V bistable solenoid valve (a bistable solenoid valve is controlled by reversing the polarities) using an ATmega328P in order to be able to control a flow of water. Everything will be on battery and therefore needs to consume as little as possible.
For now, all tests have been done at 5 V powered by USB and on 3.7 V battery.
Attempts
When I directly connect the valve between VCC and GND, whether it is with USB or battery, the valve correctly open/close.
I tried using a L9110s and a L293DNE, but with the battery, the problem is that the valve only makes a slight noise, but does not open/close. It also happens from time to time with USB, but it's probably a handling error on my part.
So I think the controllers have too big losses and don't give a high enough voltage to do anything. These are of course just assumptions, I don't know enough about it to say for sure.
Regarding the connections, I did as indicated in the datasheet:

By placing the valve in place of the motor and connecting one of the two inputs to the GND and the other to the VCC.
Values
I did some tests by measuring the voltage across the valve with the L9110s, as well as its current under different conditions.
In 5 V through USB




Voltage with valve
Voltage without valve
Current




Off
0 V

0 mA


Open
2.7 V
4.5 V
196 mA


Close
-3.3 V
-4.6 V
231 mA



And that work !
In 3.9 V through 3.7 V battery




Voltage with valve
Voltage without valve
Current




Off
0 V

0 mA


Open
1.8 V
3.3 V
140 mA


Close
-2.1 V
-3.5 V
150 mA



But here, it just makes little noises…
Finally
I would like to know if there is a way to increase the output voltage of the L9110s without consuming more when not in use. I had thought about using a DC-DC step up boost like this one, but the problem is that the L9110s reverses the polarities, and therefore I cannot connect my boost to the output of the latter.

Did you check how much current the valve requires? Are you sure your power supply can deliver that much current?

@EdgarBonet the current required for the valve is 500mA and the power supply is 2A so no problem. Additionally, the valve works correctly when I manually connect it between VCC and GND. So I don't think that's the problem . Thanks anyway for this remark!

use a transistor to drive the solenoid ... many examples on the internet

@jsotola this valve being a bistable valve, I have to reverse the polarities in order to open/close it. So I have to make an H-bridge with transistors? Isn’t that precisely the work of the l9110? I will try as soon as I have enough transistors at my disposal. Thank you for your idea!

are you certain that you have to reverse polarity?

Please measure voltage and current of the valve when you apply control signals for all three situations, off, open, close, and [edit] your question to add the results. BTW; what is the reference to Arduino? Perhaps it would be better to ask this at SE/EE?

Add a flyback diode (e.g., 1N4007) across the solenoid to protect the MOSFET from voltage spikes caused by the inductive load.

@tepalia Are you aware that the solenoid is driven in both directions? Additionally, the L9110 includes diodes for such applications.

@jsotola Yes, this is how a bistable solenoid valve works. This is also what it says in the item description, and it works correctly when I change the polarities manually.

@thebusybee I made the measurements as requested and put them in the original question.
I posted the question here because that's what I was asked when I asked on stackoverflow.com and the whole thing is controlled by an atmega328p. I'm not yet very familiar with all the available forums, so thank you for the link you provided, and I will ask there as soon as possible. THANKS

You did not yet post this question over at SE/EE, so I answer here. Anyway, it can be helpful for other Arduino users, too.

The data sheet clearly shows the saturation voltages at VCC = 9V:



Symbol
Meaning
Typical
Unit




VHout
Output high voltage
7.6
V


VLout
Output low voltage
0.45
V



So you need to take about 1.8 V voltage loss into account, and this matches your measurements.
Instead of boosting the output voltage to the solenoid, which does not work as you note, you can boost the supply voltage of the L9110. According to the data of the linked booster you should be able to use it.
The supply voltage of the L9110 does not need to be the same as that of the MCU.
The data sheet says this for the inputs:



Symbol
Meaning
Typical
Unit




VHin
Minimum input high voltage
2.5
V


VLin
Maximum input low voltage
0.7
V



This matches the output voltage produced by an ATmega328P at 3.6 V supply:



Symbol
Meaning
Typical
Unit




VOH
Minimum output high voltage (shall be higher than the value for the L9110)
2.9
V


VOL
Maximum output low voltage (shall be lower than the value for the L9110)
0.5
V



